# Get records having both values in "IN" using SQL

Tags: sql, relational-division

I need a SQL statement to extract those applicants from the database who have both the attachment tags. The belowq statement works fine if I want aaplicant who have either 7 or 8 as the attachment tag but i need applicant who have both these tags.

```
select distinct(a.id) from applicant a
join applicantdeployment ad on a.id = ad.applicantid
join ApplicantAttachment at on a.id = at.applicantid
where a.applicanttype = 'TCN/LN' and ad.groundlocation in (4,8,14) and ad.deploymentstatus =1
and ad.trainingdeploymentstatus = 6 and at.tag in (7,8)
```

For example from the below set I just want ids 7332,7451 and 7449 to show up.

ID      Tag

7328     8

7328     8

7332     8

7332     7

7337             7

7449             8

7449             7

7451     8

7453     7

7451     7

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join to the ApplicationAttachment table twice to ensure that both tags are present. That way you would avoid the need for DISTINCT and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM applicant a
JOIN applicantdeployment ad ON a.id = ad.applicantid
JOIN ApplicantAttachment at7 ON a.id = at7.applicantid AND at7.tag = 7
JOIN ApplicantAttachment at8 ON a.id = at8.applicantid AND at8.tag = 8
WHERE a.applicanttype = 'TCN/LN' 
AND ad.groundlocation IN (4,8,14)
AND ad.deploymentstatus = 1
AND ad.trainingdeploymentstatus = 6
```

Comment: I would still need distinct as i just want the IDs. and without distinct it gives multiple records for the same ID. But yes i dont need to do group by.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do below, rather than distinct:

```
GROUP BY a.id HAVING COUNT(a.id) = 2
```

Comment: This works! thanks but i was wondering what if one of the IDs has 2 records for the tag 7 itself, that would get counted then...right? for example ID 7328 has one more tag 8. Which is a posibility in my database structure. Sorry for not pointing that out earlier

Comment: @sarsha - Then do: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT at.Tag) = 2`

Comment: I tried adding a count to this as i wanted a count of IDs that satisfied this criteria and as expected it gave me a count of records per ID. so this cant work that way

Answer (score 1):

In your sample data, shouldn't 7451 also be selected? You'll need to modify the code below to fit your query, but try out the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT,
    Tag INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
(
    ID,
    Tag
)
SELECT 7328, 8 UNION
SELECT 7332, 8  UNION
SELECT 7332, 7  UNION
SELECT 7337, 7  UNION
SELECT 7449, 8  UNION
SELECT 7449, 7  UNION
SELECT 7451, 8  UNION
SELECT 7453, 7  UNION
SELECT 7451, 7

select distinct(ad.id) from #Temp ad
join #Temp at on ad.id = at.id
AND ad.Tag != at.Tag
where at.tag in (7,8)
AND ad.Tag IN (7, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the IN list items into a table called #Tags, this will work, and there won't be any need to rewrite the query if the number of tags changes.

```
select distinct(#Temp.ID)
from #Temp
where not exists (
  select * from #Tags
  where not exists (
    select * from #Temp as TempCopy
    where TempCopy.Tag = #Tags.Tag
    and TempCopy.ID = #Temp.ID
  )
)
```

In English, this selects those IDs for which none of the required tags is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select distinct(a.id)
from applicant a
join applicantdeployment ad on a.id = ad.applicantid
join (select applicantid from applicantattachment at1
join applicantattachment at2 on at1.applicantid=at.applicantid
where at1.tag=7 and at2.tag=8) at
on a.id = at.applicantid
where a.applicanttype = 'TCN/LN'
and ad.groundlocation in (4,8,14)
and ad.deploymentstatus =1
and ad.trainingdeploymentstatus = 6
```

Join the applicantattachment table to itself to get only the relevant applicantids.

Comment: I should add that this doesn't scale well to the situation where you want the tag to be all of more than two values.  Or at least you need a join for every value you want to check.

Answer (score -2):

```
select distinct(a.id) from applicant a
join applicantdeployment ad on a.id = ad.applicantid
join ApplicantAttachment at on a.id = at.applicantid
where a.applicanttype = 'TCN/LN' and ad.groundlocation in (4,8,14) and ad.deploymentstatus =1
and ad.trainingdeploymentstatus = 6 and at.tag in (7,8) and a.id IN (7332,7449);
```

Comment: I think OP meant finding a way without hard coding the result :)