# Rails Joins Query on Multiple Association Search

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have two models say User and Roles

Lets say I have 3 users "A", "B" and "C" and I have 3 roles "X", "Y", "Z"
and the relation for users is `has_many` roles

Lets assume A have role X, B have X and Y and C have role X

How should I modify my query to get B alone which have both X and Y role

This is my query which returns users with either X or Y

```
User.joins(:roles).where("roles.name IN (?)", ["X", "Y"])
```

Comment: I think you have to id with plain sql or with division in ruby code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285761/get-records-having-both-values-in-in-using-sql

Answer (score 0):

I think work will on after implement below query, I just seeing your code & implemented.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN roles ON roles.name = name").where(["name = 'X', 'Y'"])
```

**Note:** Not tested