# Laravel eloquent finding entry pairs with two destinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with three tables and a one to many relationship from the first two to `records`:

```
Table     → Columns
-----------------------------------------
Firmwares → [id, version, …]
Tests     → [id, name, …]
Records   → [id, firmware_id, test_id, …]
```

Records contains the result of one test with one firmware. I need to make querys to compare two firmware versions.

**Edit:**
Let's say I have a records table like this:

```
Records: [id, firmware_id, test_id, …]
 1, 1,  7, …
 2, 3,  7, …
 5, 1,  6, …
10, 4,  7, …
28, 1, 14, …
43, 4, 14, …
55, 4, 15, …
⋮
```

I would like get do a query with `firmware_id 1,4` a list like this:

```
Records: [id, firmware_id, test_id, …]
 1, 1,  7, …
10, 4,  7, …
28, 1, 14, …
43, 4, 14, …
⋮
```

The output only contains rows where both firmwares have a scan of the **same** test.

---

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285761/get-records-having-both-values-in-in-using-sql) but I couldn't figure out how to do this in eloquent.

---

Currently, my query looks something like this:

```php
Record::select(['id', 'firmware_id', 'test_id'])
    // Apply firmware selection
    // DO SOMETHING HERE (I think ...)
    ->whereIn('firmware_id', [$data['FirmwareA'], $data['FirmwareB']])
    // Apply test selection
    ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data) || array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
        return $query->whereIn('test_id', Test::select(['id'])
            ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('test_prop_a_id', $data['TestPropA']);
            })
            ->when(array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('id', $data['Test']);
            })
        );
    })
    ->get();
```

And I get all results containing firmware version A or B. I want a list that contains those results **only if both** are present.

#### Solutions:

- I could just do two querys, one for each firmware, and intersect the result on the `test_id`. I would have to do this in software, because MySQL has no `intersect`. Is there maybe a better way?

Using Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my question on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289734/finding-one-of-entries-to-a-composite-key-index/289738#289738) i got a [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289738/215871) from @Akina :

SQL:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 USING (b_id, c_id, d_id)
WHERE (t1.a_id, t2.a_id) IN ((1,2), (2,1))
```

I translated this to
Laravel/PHP:

```php
$table = (new Record)->getTable();
Record::join($table .' AS self', function($join) use ($table) {
        $join->on($table.'.test_id', '=', 'self.test_id');
    })
    ->select([$table.'.id', $table.'.firmware_id', $table.'.test_id'])
    // Apply firmware selection
    ->where(function($query) use ($data, $table) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($data, $table) {
            $query->where($table.'.firmware_id', '=', $data['FirmwareA'])
                ->where('self.firmware_id', '=', $data['FirmwareB']);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) use ($data, $table) {
            $query->where($table.'.firmware_id', '=', $data['FirmwareB'])
                ->where('self.firmware_id', '=', $data['FirmwareA']);
        });
    })
    // Apply test selection
    ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data) || array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
        return $query->whereIn('test_id', Test::select(['id'])
            ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('test_prop_a_id', $data['TestPropA']);
            })
            ->when(array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('id', $data['Test']);
            })
        );
    })
    ->get();
```

With `->toSql()` the query looks like this:

```
select `records`.`id`, `records`.`firmware_id`, `records`.`test_id` from `records` 
inner join `records` as `self` 
    on `records`.`test_id` = `self`.`test_id` 
where (
    (`records`.`firmware_id` = ? and `self`.`firmware_id` = ?) 
    or 
    (`records`.`firmware_id` = ? and `self`.`firmware_id` = ?)
) 
and `records`.`test_id` in (
    select `id` from `tests` 
    where `id` in (?, ?, ?) 
    and `test_prop_a_id` in (?)
)
```

This solves the main problem. There are still some improvements to be made. For example in the test selection statement.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should define one to many relationships for the model 'Record'  like 'tests' and 'records' and then you can be able to use 'Eloquent' 'has' method.

```
Record::select(['id', 'firmware_id', 'test_id'])
    // Apply firmware selection
    ->whereIn('firmware_id', [$data['FirmwareA'], $data['FirmwareB']])
    // Apply test selection
    ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data) || array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
        return $query->whereIn('test_id', Test::select(['id'])
            ->when(array_key_exists('TestPropA', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('test_prop_a_id', $data['TestPropA']);
            })
            ->when(array_key_exists('Test', $data), static function($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->whereIn('id', $data['Test']);
            })
        );
    })

->has('tests')->has('records')->get();
```

Yes, you right maybe you should try this query instead.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Record;

class Test extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function records()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Record::class);
    }
}


     $tests = Test::select(['records.id', 'records.firmware_id', 'records.test_id'])
                ->join('records', 'tests.id', '=', 'records.test_id')
                ->join('firmwares', 'firmwares.id', '=', 'records.firmware_id')
->has('records', '>=', 2)
                ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: There are one to many relationships from firmware and tests to records. I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly. I know how to select a record which has a relation to a specific test, or firmware. I want a query which selects records only if **both (two different firmwares)** have **records** of the same **test**!

Comment: Maybe your new idea could work, but this code needs a lot of refinement (Only join selected firmwares and so on…, And why do I need this Test class/factory code?). Tomorrow, I'll try to get something like this to work, if there is no better solution.

Comment: No, this doesn't work at all. Those joins don't provide any additional information to what is already in the records table.

Comment: yes maybe I just have a mistake in the definition of a relationship return $this->belongsToMany(Firmware::class, 'records');   $tests = Test::select(['tests.id as id', 'records.id as record_id', 'firmwares.id as firmware_id'])
            ->with('records')
            ->join('records', 'tests.id', '=', 'records.test_id')
            ->join('firmwares', 'firmwares.id', '=', 'records.firmware_id')

            ->has('records', '>=', 2)
            ->get()->toArray();

Comment: I think you are wrong in your assumptions about the content of those tables. Yes, there is a one-to-many relationship from the firmware to the results, but there is no result with more than one firmware. Each new firmware version is automatically tested with multiple tests and the result, which is different for each test, is saved in the results table. And no firmware is tested on the same test twice. (The result would be updated in the database.)